# Should I use double quotes throughout the paper even after defining the terms in the introductory section?

Tags: computer-science, writing-style, physics

Say I have introduced/defined some not-so-common terms like "clock register", "ancilla", etc. in the first section of a research paper, and while doing so I kept them within double quotes. However, I was wondering whether even during the subsequent occurrences of those terms I should use double quotes or not.

What's the convention regarding this in the physics and computer science communities?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The usual convention in CS:

- Use *italics* when you first mention the term and define it.
- After that, you will use it just like any other word. No italics, no boldface, no quotation marks.

Comment: This is also the convention in physics, and probably many other fields too.

Answer (score 8):

I think it would be unusual to do that, actually. However, if you want to "emphasize" the terms at each use you could use some typographic form. I would suggest *italic*, however, over double quotes. Imagine a CS paper in which every use of "list" was printed that way.

But using a typographic convention should really only be needed if the word defined is also a common word or term that is also used in its normal sense in the paper as well as its newly defined technical sense.

If you over use typographic conventions, by the way, say, ALL CAPS and **bold** and such throughout a paper without a good reason, the paper just starts to look ugly and will be harder to read. The reason I suggest *italic* above is that it is easier on the eye.

Comment: Only if you are a heavy metal writer.

Comment: In that case you should actually  **   H Ä S I Z E**  them.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yeah (banging heads)

Comment: @Buffy In a CS paper, it would be (list)

Comment: @Buffy "_banging heads_"... that... does not mean the same as headbanging...